# Number with dash and Persian text shows incorrect right to left

Tags: html, css

I has this code

```html
 <p>
    
    
             با کدنوسازی
    
            01-01-1034-100100
    
    </p>
```

But output is incorrect and shows number right to left(با کدنوسازی 01-01-1034-100100)!

I want this output (01-01-1034-100100)

please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put text at the end and the number before:

```html
<p>

 01-01-1034-100100
    با کدنوسازی

</p>
```

And the change the direction if needed:

```css
p {
 direction:rtl;
 text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<p>

 01-01-1034-100100
    با کدنوسازی

</p>
```

Comment: thanks .if i want persian text at the first then...?

Comment: @ashkufaraz check again ;)

Answer (score 2):

add this, it will solve your problem

```
<span dir="ltr">01-01-1034-100100</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the dir attribute to the text you want to display left to right, like this:

```html
 <p>
    
    
             <span>با کدنوسازی</span>
    
            <span dir="ltr">01-01-1034-100100</span>
    
    </p>
```